# Default access fields inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, default, protected

Are the fields or the methods of class with `default` access inhereted to the subclasses when they both exist in the same package, or should they be still declared as `protected`?

Example:

```
package mypackage;

class A{
  int x = 3;
}    

class B extends A{
}
```

Has the `B` class also a field `x`?

Comment: you can do simple practical exercise  and find the answer.

Comment: *Every* field is inherited, even `private` fields. The fact that the subclass can’t access it does not mean that it is not there. Still, every instance of the subclass will have all fields from its base class, i.e. reserved memory for it, and if the subclass can’t access them it might still invoke inherited accessible methods which might use them.

Comment: Btw, how can such a question be “urgent” to someone not having a compiler?

Answer (score 3):

See description:

[image]

Hope it will sort things out

**[EDIT]**

From table for default modifier like in your case:

> Accessed only from within the package in witch they are declared.

Means if class `A` and `B` stay under the same package, you can for example print out the `x`:

```
class B extends A{

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        new B().init();     
    }

    private void init() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }   
}
```

However, if we put class `B` to different package, an error will be thrown: `The type mypackage.A is not visible`. So here you must set `public` modifier.

Comment: Ok I have read that but it does not clarify if the default fields are inhereted by the subclasses of the same package.

Answer (score 1):

With `default` access the properties are only visible to classes in same package.

But with `protected` access they are accessible to all classes in same package and subclasses (regardless of package). Choose what is relevant in your context.

> Has the B class also a field x?

Yes `B` inherits the property `x` of `A`

Comment: Protected access makes the fields visible to the classes of the same package as well, regardless if they are subclasses or not.

Comment: @arjacsoh Thanks for correcting that, I got flipped in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the `public` , `default`(If classes are in same package) and `protected` data members using inheritance:

```
public class A {
    int a;
}

public class B extends A {

    B() {
        a = 5;
    }
```

Comment: That's true only if the subclass is in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of default sub class [if in the same package] has the privilege to use the methods/data members.

```
class B extends Class A{
     System.out.println(new B().x); //will surely work in your case(Example shown).
}
```